# Running python script several times with different parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, subprocess, discord.py

I want to run a script like this one below multiple times at the same time but using different tokens for each time, for which I already have a list of tokens.

The question is, how do I get to run this script n number of times (number of tokens), at the same time?

I have tried threading, but it didn't work, most likely due to the async functions (for which I don't have much experience). I have also tried having all the script inside one function with the token as a parameter, but the async functions were preventing it somehow, as well?

Is there some way doing this using subprocess, or such?

```
import module

client = module.Client()


async def on_some_event():
    do_something_using_current_client_token

def ask_for_something():
    return something


ask_for_something()
client.run(token)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is "at the same time" a requirement, or an expression to mean "run the functions in a manner that makes it seem like they are running at the same time?" Fact is, to run things "at the same time" in Python you'll need to use the multiprocess library, and that comes with some hefty disadvantages if true concurrency is something you don't really need for the task at hand.

Comment: The thing is, when the script runs, it does not end unless manually done so; as it stays listening on the token supplied. If I waited for one to finish before the other starts, I will have to firstly close connection with the first token.

What I want to do, however, is to stay logged into all the tokens at the same time with the script(s) running respectively for each token. Therefore, I am not looking for true concurrency, the scripts can start and end at different times, just as long as they run at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply needed to add `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())` at the very start, as asyncio's loops only ran in the main thread and not the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of tokens with `N` items, the code below will loop through the list of tokens and run in parallel spawn `N` threads with the token as an argument:

```py
import threading
import time

def doWork(token):
    count = 0
    while count < 3:
        print('Doing work with token', token)
        time.sleep(1)
        count+=1

N = 3
tokens = [n for n in range(N)]
threads = []

for token in tokens:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=doWork, args=(token,))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

for i, thread in enumerate(threads):
    thread.join()
    print('Done with thread', i)
```

The output:

```
Doing work with token 0
Doing work with token 1
Doing work with token 2
Doing work with token 1
Doing work with token 2
Doing work with token 0
Doing work with token 1
Doing work with token 2
Doing work with token 0
Done with thread 0
Done with thread 1
Done with thread 2
```

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that before, but I get this error:
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-4'.
Most likely due to the async functions inside the script. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you running async functions? If you copy-paste the answer, and then modify the ```doWork``` function and make the ```tokens``` list be your actual list of tokens, it will do what you need.

Comment: discord.py module, which is dependent on events like async def on_message()

Comment: Yes, it will definitely work if the script did not have async functions, because then this error occurs, which traces back to the asyncio/events.py library. RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-N'.

Comment: Ok, so do you *need* to do this with async functions? If so I can come up with a solution for that.

Comment: Yeah. That would be great.

Comment: Try the syncio solution I added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229906/discussion-between-lnogueir-and-chaocius).

Answer (score 1):

Asyncio solution:

```py
import asyncio

async def doWork(token):
    count = 0
    while count < 3:
        print('Doing work with token', token)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        count+=1

N = 3
tokens = [n for n in range(N)]
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([doWork(token) for token in tokens]))
print('Done')
```

Output:

```
Doing work with token 2
Doing work with token 0
Doing work with token 1
Doing work with token 2
Doing work with token 0
Doing work with token 1
Doing work with token 2
Doing work with token 0
Doing work with token 1
Done
```

Comment: I got this error 'TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required'

Comment: Let's try to figure this out here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229906/discussion-between-lnogueir-and-chaocius